# Clarify on adjoint equivalences

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:\Bbb A\to \Bbb B$ be a functor that is an equivalence of categories, with quasi-inverse $G:\Bbb B\to \Bbb A$; call $\eta: 1_\Bbb A\to GF$ and $\varepsilon:FG\to 1_\Bbb B$ the two natural isomorphisms that come with the equivalence.

If I understood correctly, one recovers two adjoint equivalences $F\dashv G$, one with unity $\eta$ and one with counity $\varepsilon$. But one also has two adjoint equivalences $G\dashv F$, choosing $\varepsilon^{-1}$ as unity or $\eta^{-1}$ as counity, right?

I'd say yes; take for example the adjoint equivalence $F\dashv G$ with unity $\eta$, and say counity $\xi$. Then $\xi^{-1}$ and $\eta^{-1}$ satisfy the triangle identities for an adjunction $G\dashv F$. Look at the first identity: $$G\xrightarrow{G\xi^{-1}}GFG\xrightarrow{\eta_G^{-1}}G,$$ that since inverses are unique is actually $$G\xrightarrow{\eta _G}GFG\xrightarrow{G\xi}G,$$ that is just the second identity of $F\dashv G$.

So in general our equivalence yields two bijections between $\Bbb B (F-,-)$ and $\Bbb A(-,G-)$, but one is not the inverse of the other, unless the equivalence is adjoint; and similarly for $\Bbb A (G-,-)$ and $\Bbb B(-,F-)$.

It seems that this conclusion makes sense, but I'm quite confused by all the commutative diagrams that arise in category theory; thanks for any clarify.